# Escaping in Html

Tags: javascript, html, security, escaping

I need to make my code secure from XSS, so far I have found out that I have to escape my html,

I know I have to escape the following:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
(   &#40;
)   &#41;
#   &#35;
&   &amp;
"   &quot;
```

I change the above characters in my code but the code shows as a string on the browser, I do not know where to escape them and basically how to escape them in order to work correctly, can anyone help on this?

Comment: XSS and SQL injection are the terms you need to Google.

Comment: ssh/sftp/ftp/webserver/(linux/windows/bsd)/firewall security :3 maybe you have open mysql ports or default mongodb install with anonymous access (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say input fields, but that's really not all that matters. You see, anything that isn't decided in PHP can be influenced by a user. With this in mind, I'm speaking of `ajax` calls, and `routing`.

For example, do you use user-friendly urls? In that case you probably route the url through your database? Then that is no different from an input. Any `$_GET` or `$_POST` is a vulnerability. You will always have to escape anything you get from these requests as users can influence it.

This means an ajax call where you send data through the `$_GET` or `$_POST`, or routing where you basically say (also `$_GET`) `index.php?page=pagename`.

This would result in `$_GET['page']` and should be escaped if you're making it go through a database.

Comment: I want to note that the original question has been edited to turn into an almost entirely different question. Therefore my answer seems completely random and meant for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Can external users directly access your database?  If so, they may be able to brute force db passwords (attackers first try would be default passwords), and from there, take total control of the machine hosting your website.  See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/levraging-a-shell-from-sql-injection) and [this](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/anatomy-of-an-attack-gaining-reverse-shell-from-sql-injection/).  Do not have direct access to your database from the public internet.

Generally, you should look at what ports are open, using [nmap](https://nmap.org/).  Only have the minimum ports open that you need.  Any other port could be a door open for an attacker.  If the attacker gains a shell on your system, he may be able to do whatever he wants: take down your system, host rubbish, insert backdoors that grab your password when you login, and lots of other evil stuff.  For example, [recently](http://devco.re/blog/2016/04/21/how-I-hacked-facebook-and-found-someones-backdoor-script-eng-ver/) a white hat hacker got shell access on a facebook network, and discovered exactly such a backdoor for recovering staff passwords on that system (i.e. some black hat got there before him and did evil stuff).

What about the software hosting your website?  Is it up-to-date?  There are a lot of vulnerabilities in out-of-date PHP systems that hackers love to exploit, allowing them to get shell access.

Finally, how do you login to your website to update the content?  Is it through VPN?  Does it require two-factor authentication?  If not, then attacker may simply access the admin content of the website the same way you do, and brute force your password.  Ouch!

Answer (score 0):

You should look out for a SQL injection as well as security problems on the server itself (like PHP, webserver, etc.). So you should always take care the software is up-to-date and preventing a SQL injection is easy by using, for example, PDO with parametrized queries.